# Device tree and driver probing

Tags: linux, driver, device-tree

In Linux device tree files (DTS), how does the `compatible` entry work if more than one option is given? It seems that this is **not** a choice between these entries, but that layered devices are also possible (p.e. I have a line like `compatible = "vendor,controller-uart", "vendor, controller-serial"` that seems to associate both driver `controller-serial` and `controller-uart` (where in terms of code, `controller-serial` actually calls stuff from `controller-uart`).

Where is this concept explained? I could not find this explained in the general device tree documentation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overview/reference manual for Open Firmware Device Trees](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320868/overview-reference-manual-for-open-firmware-device-trees)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question (from information in [this document](http://ols.fedoraproject.org/OLS/Reprints-2008/likely2-reprint.pdf)): this was a misunderstanding on my part. It is actually a choice, and the usage of the second device type specified under `compatible` from within the code was an implementation detail of the driver in question.